# DataBinding: 'ClassLibrary.SubCategoryModel' does not contain a property with the name 'objCat'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Error:

> DataBinding: 'ClassLibrary.SubCategoryModel' does not contain a property with the name 'objCat'

Grid view control of SubCategories.aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridSubCategories" Height="156px" Width="240px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gridSubCategories_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryID" HeaderText="Sub Category ID" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="SubCategoryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryName" HeaderText="Sub Category" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="objCat.CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="objCat.CategoryName" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="EnableEdit" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>" Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteCategory" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>" Text="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code throwing error:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    gridSubCategories.DataSource = sda.GetSubCategories();
    gridSubCategories.DataBind();
}
```

Class definitions:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategoryModel
{
    public CategoryModel objCat = new CategoryModel();
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

GetSubCategories Method:

```
public List<SubCategoryModel> GetSubCategories()
{
    List<SubCategoryModel> listSubCatList = new List<SubCategoryModel>();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetSubCategories"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                SubCategoryModel subcatObj = new SubCategoryModel();
                subcatObj.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["SubCategoryID"]);
                //subcatObj.objCat.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["CategoryID"]);
                subcatObj.objCat.CategoryName = sdr["CategoryName"].ToString();
                subcatObj.SubCategoryName = sdr["SubCategoryName"].ToString();

                listSubCatList.Add(subcatObj);
            }
            con.Close();
            return listSubCatList;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the data is being fetched and passed to DataSource of the gridview:
[Contents of DataSource property of the gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdOqZ.png)

Why objCat is not identified as a property inside CategoryModel class? Is there any other ways to bind object inside objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding a list of classes to a GridView. Then I recommend switching to strongly typed data controls by adding `ItemType`. Then you can access the properties by using `Item`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="SubCategoryModel">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.SubCategoryID %>
                <%# Item.objCat.CategoryName %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```